# Question on Dirichlet Character conductor (please read description)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

So I'm reading a paper on *"The Dirichlet L-Series"* (link below) and came across this:

We'll define the Dirichlet Character:

> $$\chi \space : \space (\mathbb{Z}/f\mathbb{Z})^\times \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$$

Such that $\space f \space$ is the conductor of $\space \chi$.

There is a statement made in the paper saying:

> If $\space f \space$ is the conductor of $\space \chi \space$, then $\space \big|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \chi(i) \big| \le f \space$ for all $\space n \space$.

Can someone please explain why this is true?

I've been looking everywhere online and can't seem to find a proof for this.

Here is the link to the paper, the statement is in **Page 2** at the start of the proof for **Lemma 1.5**:

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/classes/254a/lectures/22.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $\chi$ is non-trivial $\sum_{i=1}^f\chi(i)=0$.
As $\chi$ has period $f$ then for $n=qf+r$ ($0\le r<f$) then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\chi(f)=\sum_{i=qf+1}^{qf+r}\chi(i).$$
This last sum has $<f$ terms.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment (which I now deleted). Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't the sum on the left sum over values $\space \chi(i) \space$ and not $\space \chi(f) \space$ ?